# Why are my JS scripts only working when linked within the "head" section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, getuikit

I asked a question yesterday who's answer was "your JS isn't linked properly". Here is my question now: Why is it the scripts are only loading when the link is in the `head` section and not in the `body` section? I was taught to place them in the very bottom of the body, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Number Crunchers</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta class="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/newcustom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cards.css">
    <!--
    <script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    -->
</head>
<body>
    <!--Page Content-->

    <script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the `script` is at the bottom is there nothing works. However when I put it with the ones at the top everything works. Why?

Comment: Do you have some other script which relies on jquery.js in the head? Have you at least checked the console to see what the error is when you move the JS around?

Comment: I don't think so. I copied the whole head from my code, and I don't see anything pop up in the console.

Comment: In that case, what 'doesn't work'? How does the behaviour change between them? You're not giving us a lot to work with here. Given your code samples, the logic shouldn't be affected

Comment: According to the UIkit documentation, jQuery has to be imported **before** the UIkit code.

Comment: Do you have console error messages?

Comment: No. No console error messages.

Comment: @Pointy I did think that was the case - although OP states it works from the `head` in this order, and that there's no errors in the console. I can only think this is a reduced sample of the original code which has masked the actual problem.

Comment: @Caleb could you give us a more complete sample of your code - or at least the `<script>` you're adding.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan reading more of the UIkit documentation, it appears to listen to DOM manipulation events so that it can do stuff to the DOM while it's being built. If that's the case, then that would explain why it has to be imported before the `<body>`.

Comment: HTML markup: https://getuikit.com/docs/introduction#html-markup and an alternate option: https://getuikit.com/docs/javascript#load-scripts

Comment: (Though the UIkit docs *also* say that the `<script>` tags can have the "defer" attribute, so maybe not.)

Comment: here is my whole code on JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/CheshirePanda/9dmgeuax/

Comment: And since I'm new to this, why is my question getting down-voted?I don't understand what's going on so I asked a question...

Comment: @Caleb I didn't downvote, but when asking a question about why something "doesn't work" it's very helpful to explain what that means: what your expectations are, what happens instead, what you've done so far to investigate, and so on.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you. I wasn't sure how to ask questions here yet. that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading them before `</body>` is fine, the thing is `jquery` should be the first one, and you also have some typos (see img below) which break the code afterwards, therefore they would only load before these (when in `<head>`)

```
<body>
<!--Page Content-->
        ...
<!--Javascript to make the world go round -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

See here these typos (after "check" and after "program"):

[image]

Comment: Then why would it work if it was loaded in the head tag in the same order?

Comment: He had `<` typos, therefore they would load before these errors.